How does WordPress determine if a server supports pretty permalinks?
I am trying to get pretty permalinks to function with OpenBSD httpd.
However, I cannot test my configurations because WordPress only offers the option of almost pretty permalinks.
What does WordPress use to determine if it should offer pretty permalinks as a configuration option?
If an answer or comment isn't explaining how WordPress performs this test, then it is not addressing the question.

what does it mean "almost pretty permalinks."

Almost pretty permalinks use the format http://example.com/index.php/yyyy/mm/dd/post-name/. See https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/customize-permalinks/ for more information.

if you want an answer you should put all details in your question, for example what is your web server (appach,ngix, lightspeed, other) and what is its configuration. at least in terms of relevant moduls

I stated in the question that the server software is OpenBSD httpd. If you are not familiar with this, that is okay, but note that I have gone very deep in search results and the current version of OpenBSD (or any version that supports rewrite rules) httpd, there is not a single post anywhere that has a configuration to support WordPress pretty permalinks. So I seem to be a trailblazer and the first problem I'm running into is WordPress doesn't offer the option of pretty permalinks, so I cannot tell if the configuration would work or not.

I am able to find many screenshots of the WordPress permalinks page in the dashboard and that page shows options that are already in the pretty permalinks format. This seems to indicate that WordPress has something it uses to determine that the server supports pretty permalinks, so the server configuration is not directly relevant to the test, as the test is being performed by WordPress, itself, and that is the thing I am trying to discover.

should everyone be an expert in the differences between openbsd, freebsd and netbsd I would assume each has a nonexisting market share as web servers? httpd is not a name of a web server.... but getting your question better is realy up to you, if you don't want I am cool with that. On a constructive side I find chatgpt to be very good at technical quesions of this kind, I would guess it is much better than trying to figure out a good phrasing to feed search engines

Yes, httpd is the name of a web sever. I updated the question with a link to the OpenBSD man page for httpd. OpenBSD is what the web server was created for. As I stated in my previous comment, it doesn't matter if you are not familiar with the web server because the question is not about the web server, it is about WordPress and learning how WordPress determines whether a server supports pretty permalinks. Given you were not familiar with the term "almost pretty permalinks", which is used in the WordPress documentation, this may be an aspect of WordPress you are not qualified to answer.

chatgpt say that your websever is misconfigured. me: wordpress can not access your webser configuration therefor a possible reason is that php do not report properly the capabilities of your web server.

Yet another demonstration of how worthless chatgpt is for this sort of problem.

guess you just don't like answers you don't like, therefor you call them worthless... you not the first here thinking like that

Given that httpd is a very minor webserver by market share and didn't support rewrites until OpenBSD 6.6, it's not really surprising that WP hasn't been written to accommodate it.
The basic structure that WP requires is if the request is not for an extant file or directory, to rewrite it to index.php in the root of the site. You're going to have to implement that yourself. The guide at openbsdhandbook.com only acknowledges OpenBSD 6.4, so obviously there's no mention there of how it implements rewrites.
Otherwise, it might be a better idea to use a supported and better documented webserver like nginx.
Digging into it a little further: the actual test for rewriting is carried out by got_url_rewrite(), which by default returns true if one of the below conditions is satisfied:

Apache's mod_rewrite module is loaded
$GLOBALS['is_nginx'] is set
$GLOBALS['is_caddy'] is set
iis7_supports_permalinks() returns true

Provided you have rewrites correctly configured the below should work for you:
function wpse427660_got_rewrite() {
    return true;
}

add_filter( 'got_url_rewrite', 'wpse427660_got_rewrite' );


The question is exclusively about WordPress and how WordPress performs a test. The URL structure is fixed in the dashboard and the only configuration options come after http://www.example.com/index.php/. The web server software is only relevant to the results that are provided by whatever test WordPress runs to configure this option. Successfully configuring for this option is made easier if I can understand how the test is performed. Your answer doesn't address how the test is performed.

Edited with some more details for you.

Thank you. This helps a ton. Do you have a recommendation on where I can place this?

Quick and dirty method would be to throw it in your theme's functions.php. A slightly more elegant method would be to create a site-specific plugin since it's functionality that doesn't really belong in a theme.

I added that code to the bottom of functions.php and right away pretty permalinks are functioning.

I also submitted a Trac enhancement ticket. If the server is determined by the Server host header, the same issue will arise with other servers, such as freenginx.

In wp-includes/vars.php the line that begins with $is_nginx can include a second test for str_contains( $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'OpenBSD httpd' ). I think that the OpenBSD server response is nearly the same as or identical to the official NGINX configuration. I added $is_nginx = ( str_contains( $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'nginx' ) || str_contains( $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'OpenBSD httpd' ) ); to functions.php and the responses from WordPress are the same, but I'm just guessing because I really don't know PHP or WordPress. Will that cause me any issues?

Another option is to use $is_nginx by placing the following line in functions.php:
<?php

$is_nginx = ( str_contains( $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'OpenBSD httpd' ));

This will force WordPress to respond the same as it would with nginx as it is the same test performed for nginx in vars.php[1]:
$is_nginx = ( str_contains( $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'nginx' ) );

Other things impacted by this can be discovered by searching the code base for is_nginx.
[1] https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.7.1/src/wp-includes/vars.php#L127
